# How to call function depending on onmessage from websocket?

Tags: javascript, html

So I have this project webpage with timer.
and I made websocket test server and connected to my project webpage(client).
I want the webpage's timer to start&stop depending on message from server.
for instance, if server sends "12", timer srats and if "24" timer to stop.

```js
webSocket.onmessage = (event) => {
  alert(event.data);
  if (event.data ===12) {
    start();
    console.log('right');
  }
  if (event.data ===24) {
    reset();
    console.log('right2');
  }
};
```

Above is part of my websocket script. However, I can see the console.log, which means server&client is communicating well, but the function isn't working.

I put websocket script in between my `<head>` and `<body>`. and timer&other js in the end of my html field as script src. if I put my websocket script in the same file as my other js, websocket won't work.

Tried to put websocket in various location but won't work.

Comment: you should use `===` for checking value in if statement

Comment: just realized, tried that, still won't work :(. thank you thouh!

Comment: Based on the code you posted, you could be comparing against `event.data` not `onmessage`

Comment: just edited, but still not working.. :(

Comment: Is `event.data` a number or string?

Comment: Stop using `alert`, it blocks the JS thread, something  you really don't want to do when you're working with web sockets. You're already using console.log, _just use that_. Also note that "the function isn't working" doesn't mean anything. It's working exactly the way you wrote it so instead describe what you _do_ see happening, and how that differs from what you expected. Does the function get called at all? Does `event` have the data you expected? Show what's in it, in your post. Messages are strings, you're comparing numbers, are you sure that's going to work? Etc.